# call script ssjs in content page salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, ssjs, cloudpage

I have an ssjs script which contains functions with variables, I want to make a form in html (in content page for example) i want manually enter the data then run it directly in my ssjs,

My question: is it possible to include ssjs in html and how to do for my case ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Server-Side Javascript is executed first (on the server) and the output is then “sent” to the client where client side code is executed - you cannot do it the other way around, eg. get the form data using client side javascript and process it with SSJS on the same page. You would have to either send the form data to a form handler page or a code resource or reload your page to be able to process the data using SSJS.

I have described exactly the same process but with AMPscript here: [Create a Sales Cloud-integrated lead capture form using AMPscript](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/)

Comment: @Dadoo - if this answer helped you, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark - thanks!